# Speed up MYSQL LARGE query

Tags: php, mysql, server-side

I have a problem with a very large MYSQL query that is processing for more than 10 min for displaying records.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (
        SELECT 't-0' as typo, sh_inquiry.id as ref, sh_inquiry.pid as pid, partner, sh_inquiry.order, if(p_status IS NULL OR p_status = 0,'not paid','paid') as payment, p_voucher, country, city, delivery_date, sh_inquiry.amount as c_amount, currency as c_currency, NULL as s_amount, NULL as s_currency, IF(confirmed=0,if(delivered=0,"not confirmed","delivered"),if(delivered=0,"confirmed","delivered")) as conf
        FROM   sh_inquiry
        LEFT JOIN sh_orders ON sh_inquiry.id = sh_orders.i_id
                LEFT JOIN sh_partners ON sh_partners.pid = sh_inquiry.pid
                LEFT JOIN sh_currency ON sh_currency.id = sh_inquiry.curr_id
                LEFT JOIN sh_country ON sh_country.id = sh_inquiry.cid
                LEFT JOIN sh_debts ON sh_inquiry.id = sh_debts.i_id
        WHERE  sh_inquiry.del = 0 AND sh_inquiry.type = 1 AND sh_orders.del = 0
        UNION
                SELECT 't-1' as typo, sh_orders.i_id as ref, sid as pid, partner, sh_inquiry.order, if(p_status IS NULL OR p_status = 0,'not paid','paid') as payment, p_voucher, country, city, delivery_date, NULL as c_amount, NULL as c_currency, sh_orders.amount as s_amount, currency as s_currency, IF(confirmed=0,if(delivered=0,'not confirmed','delivered'),if(delivered=0,'confirmed','delivered')) as conf FROM sh_orders
                LEFT JOIN sh_partners ON sh_partners.pid = sh_orders.sid
                LEFT JOIN sh_currency ON sh_currency.id = sh_orders.curr_id
                LEFT JOIN sh_inquiry ON sh_inquiry.id = sh_orders.i_id
                LEFT JOIN sh_country ON sh_country.id = sh_inquiry.cid
                LEFT JOIN sh_debts ON sh_orders.id = sh_debts.o_id
                WHERE sh_orders.del = 0 AND sh_inquiry.del = 0
        ) AS U

        ORDER BY typo ASC, delivery_date
                    asc
        LIMIT 0, 10
```

The problem is that I am using 2 tables that must be joined in a single one (those 2 tables are very large), that is why I am using the UNION statement. I am displaying the records in a jquery datatables serverside page, so limiting the displayed records is not helping the cause.

Can anyone come up with a ideea about speeding up this query?
If you need more info about the structure of the database, please ask.

The EXPLAIN statment fired:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    17630   Using filesort
2   DERIVED     sh_orders   ALL     i_id    NULL    NULL    NULL    8696    Using where
2   DERIVED     sh_inquiry  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY     4   reur3918_sh.sh_orders.i_id  1   Using where
2   DERIVED     sh_partners     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   reur3918_sh.sh_inquiry.pid  1   
2   DERIVED     sh_currency     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   reur3918_sh.sh_inquiry.curr_id  1   
2   DERIVED     sh_country  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   reur3918_sh.sh_inquiry.cid  1   
2   DERIVED     sh_debts    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    18678   
3   UNION   sh_orders   ALL     i_id    NULL    NULL    NULL    8696    Using where
3   UNION   sh_partners     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   reur3918_sh.sh_orders.sid   1   
3   UNION   sh_currency     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   reur3918_sh.sh_orders.curr_id   1   
3   UNION   sh_inquiry  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY     4   reur3918_sh.sh_orders.i_id  1   Using where
3   UNION   sh_country  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   reur3918_sh.sh_inquiry.cid  1   
3   UNION   sh_debts    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    18678   
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union2,3>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

After indexing all id's the query is taking about 133 seconds..

Comment: basic rule of thumb: put indexes on any field used in a decision context. `where`, `join`, `order`, `group`, etc...

Comment: How many rows in each table?  It'll give us an idea of which types of optimizations you've probably already tried, and what you're really up against.

Comment: Execute an EXPLAIN for your query to see what indexes it's actually using ad how it's being executed

Comment: The sh_inquiry and sh_orders have eachone about 8000 records, the sh_partners has about 1500 records and sh_debts is the biggest with about 17000 records. The other ones have less then 300 records, but them also contribute to the huge amount of time spent on processing

Comment: Under 50,000 total records doesn't sound like all that much.  Start by indexing each field that is used in a `JOIN`.  e.g.: `sh_orders.id = sh_debts.o_id` => index `sh_orders.id` and `sh_debts.o_id` if they aren't both already indexed you have problems.  It sounds like one thing you're saying is "I have to `UNION` because it's so much data."?  I've never found `UNION` to speed anything up much.

Comment: No, sorry for beeing misunderstood, but the UNION statment is not used for speeding up query.. this is used because it is a mandatory requirment from business view so I was reinforcing the ideea that you wouldn't come and say to split the query

Comment: If that is your explain, indexing just the two foreign columns in `debt` table would probably give you a great speed improvement.  `sh_debts.o_id` and `sh_debts.i_id`.  You should index all of "foreign" columns in all tables however for best result.  `ALTER TABLE sh_debts ADD INDEX index_iid (i_id), ADD INDEX index_oid (o_id);`

Comment: Are you checked this tip about QL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS?  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Comment: @Mark Baker After indexing all required fields, I have tested the query with and without SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, and it was a difference of about 2-3sec between them. It took them about 79sec to process

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for you ideas!
Actually, running the EXPLAIN statment helped me to find wich table does not have the INDEX defined.
After adding INDEX to all fields that have been used into the query (mainly in JOIN ON clause), the running time has decreased to 0.83seconds